# What are solutions to the convex hull problem?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, computational-geometry, divide-and-conquer

I have researched multiple solutions to the convex hull problem, but I am afraid I don't really understand some of them. For example, Graham's scan is a bit confusing as it is not very clear if the n given points are sorted at the start of the algorithm or not. And if they are, how and why? I guess I don't really know what is meant by sorting the points by x-coordinate. In any case, I would also like to see all possible algorithms with time complexity analyses of this problem. I am aware there is a way to solve it in o(n) time, how exactly? Divide-and-conquer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Graham's scan and monotone chain run in $O(n \log n)$ when unsorted but $O(n)$ when lexicographically sorted. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms. Read related questions on the side bar.